# How to wait for page and get source when it redirects

Tags: python, selenium, redirect, selenium-webdriver

How to wait when it redirects the page by ajax

So I tried making code. but this code is not perfect.

## Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

URL = "http://www.someajaxcode.com";
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.find_element(By.ID,'SomeAjaxButton').click()
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != URL)
driver.get(driver.current_url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
print(source_code)
```

Temporarily. I prevent redirect by `driver.get(driver.current_url)`

because It doesn't keep getting the redirect page until download website completely.

so If I input the code `driver.get(driver.current_url)` at 11 line. It keep waiting the page until download website completely

but I think It's temporary code made by `driver.get(driver.current_url)`.

and then I know

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(By.ID,'anyitem at redict'))
```

but this code is getting one item element. So I don't want to this code

what if. have you know code better than this code? like something check changing all elements

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to wait for all ajax requests to complete on a page?